# How to download a skype recorded session in linux?

Tags: skype, command-line-tool

I need to download a video that has been recorded in a Skype group with a computer that I only have access through command-line (with ssh).

in the Skype desktop app, it's only possible to click on the download button and save the video in the internal disk. as I don't have access to a graphical interface, this option is not available.

the other option may be to use the Skype [export chat history and files](https://go.skype.com/export). I did that and got a download link. but when trying to get that file with **wget** in the terminal I get an "Authentication failed" error.

> Resolving neu1-api.asm.skype.com (neu1-api.asm.skype.com)...
>   52.114.77.24 Connecting to neu1-api.asm.skype.com (neu1-api.asm.skype.com)|52.114.77.24|:443... connected. HTTP request
>   sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
>
> Username/Password Authentication Failed.

is there a way so that I can download the videos using the command-line or login to Skype so that I can download the exported file?